# Search and delete matches of patterns array

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I made an array of filenames of files in which match an pattern:

```
lista=($(grep -El "<LastVisitedURL>.+</LastVisitedURL>.*<FavoriteTopic>0</FavoriteTopic>" *))
```

Now I would delete in a file index.xml all tags enclosure which contains the filenames in the array.

```
for e in ${lista[*]}
do
  sed '/\<TopicKey FileName=\"$e\"\>.*\<\/TopicKey\>/d' index.xml
done
```

The complete script is:

```
#! /bin/bash

#search xml files watched and no favorites.
lista=($(grep -El "<LastVisitedURL>.+</LastVisitedURL>.*<FavoriteTopic>0</FavoriteTopic>" *))
#declare -p lista
for e in ${lista[*]}
do
  sed '/<TopicKey FileName=\"$e\">.*<\/TopicKey>/d' index.xml
done
```

Even though the regex pattern doesn't work, `-i` option in sed for edit in place index.xml, reload index file many times how filenames have the array, and this is bad.

Any suggestions?

Comment: To edit a xml file, use `xmlstarlet`

Comment: xmlstarlet is useful.  Thanks Quenot and to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example using [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) in a shell :

```
% cat file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                                                                     
<root>
<foobar>aaa</foobar>
<LastVisitedURL>http://foo.bar/?a=1</LastVisitedURL>
<LastVisitedURL>http://foo.bar/?a=2</LastVisitedURL>
<LastVisitedURL>http://foo.bar/?a=3</LastVisitedURL>
</root>
```

Then, the command line :

```
% xmlstarlet edit --delete '//LastVisitedURL' file.xml                                                             
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <foobar>aaa</foobar>
</root>
```